# VHDL power sequencer

Tags: vhdl, simulation

I'm trying to create a power sequencer in VHDL, this is my code:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity PowerSeq is
    port (
            RESET : out std_logic;
            POWER : out std_logic;
            EN : out std_logic;
            CLOCK : out std_logic;
            SERIAL : out std_logic;
            ModuleEN : in std_logic;
            ModuleCLK : in std_logic
    );
end PowerSeq;

architecture ArchiPowerSeq of PowerSeq is
    signal counter :integer :=0;
    signal StopCount :std_logic := '0';

    begin
        process(ModuleCLK)
        begin
            if ModuleEN = '0' then
                    RESET <= '0';
                    POWER <= '1';
                    EN <= '0';
                    CLOCK <= '0';
                    SERIAL <= '0';
            end if;
            if (rising_edge(ModuleCLK) and StopCount = '0') then
                counter <= counter + 1;
            end if;
            -- 1ms = 250000
            case counter is
                when 2500000 =>
                    EN <= '1';
                when 5000000 =>
                    POWER <= '0';
                when 7500000 =>
                    CLOCK <= '1';
                when 10000000 =>
                    RESET <= '1';
                when 12500000=>
                    SERIAL <= '1';
                    StopCount <= '1';
                when others =>
            end case;

end process;

end ArchiPowerSeq;
```

I've an input clock of 250Mhz(just for example, I've also tryed lower as 50Mhz).

Simulating PowerSeq VHDL code works like expected, but when i Synthesize it and simulate Synthesized code in simulation tool I have correct EN input and Clock input but I have all X on outputs. Programming device my outputs are blocked with this values:

```
RESET <= '0';
POWER <= '1';
EN <= '0';
CLOCK <= '0';
SERIAL <= '0';
```

What is wrong with this code?

UPDATED CODE as suggested by first comment:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity PowerSeq is
    port (
            RESET : out std_logic;
            POWER : out std_logic;
            EN : out std_logic;
            CLOCK : out std_logic;
            SERIAL : out std_logic;
            ModuleEN : in std_logic;
            ModuleCLK : in std_logic
    );
end PowerSeq;

architecture ArchiPowerSeq of PowerSeq is
    signal counter :integer :=0;
    signal StopCount :std_logic := '0';

    begin
        process(ModuleCLK)
        begin
            if (rising_edge(ModuleCLK) and StopCount = '0') then
               if ModuleEN = '0' then
                   RESET <= '0';
                   POWER <= '1';
                   EN <= '0';
                   CLOCK <= '0';
                   SERIAL <= '0';
               end if;
               counter <= counter + 1;

            -- 1ms = 250000
               case counter is
                when 2500000 =>
                    EN <= '1';
                when 5000000 =>
                    POWER <= '0';
                when 7500000 =>
                    CLOCK <= '1';
                when 10000000 =>
                    RESET <= '1';
                when 12500000=>
                    SERIAL <= '1';
                    StopCount <= '1';
                when others =>

               end case;
             end if;
       end process;

end ArchiPowerSeq;
```

Comment: First, put the Case statement inside the clocked part. Then, either do nthe same to the Reset part (synchronous reset) or add the reset signal to the sensitivity list. Then fix any simulation errors that introduces. Make sure the reset (ModuleEn) and clock are correctly driven in your testbench, and re-synth, then try again.

Comment: I've corrected code as you can see above, but when I simulate synth code I continue to get X as output.

Comment: now I can see you never reset Counter or StopCount. Variable or signal  initialisations may not be supported for synthesis.

Comment: `signal counter :integer :=0;`That's not resetting it, that's signal initialisation. See prev comment.

Comment: Solved, I've reset Counter and StopCount in ModuleEN. Can you explain me why should I reset Counter and StopCount in process if I already assing them value 0 when I declare them?

Comment: Initial value is the value the circuit starts with. It generally works with flash-based fpga (the initial value is loaded by the bitstream), but not with ASIC one-time programmable FPGA since there is no initialization. In those case, and quite often for flash based FPGA, the reset plays that role. The reset is a physical pin on the flip-flop, initialization doesn't really have a "global" interpretation, and may well be unsupported. As a side note, post-map simulation may not support initialization value event if the FPGA does.